# Informatic REST API failing with 404

Tags: java, rest, informatica

We are trying to consume the Informatica 10.1.0 REST API but it is failing at login itself with 404, and there is no error message from the server. response is blank

Ours is NOT cloud. It is an ON PREM installation.

The manual URL is

```
http://<SERVER>:<PORT>/tdm/
```

So my login REST CALL is:

```
POST http://<SERVER>:<PORT>/ma/api/v2/user/login HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 60
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)

{
"@type": "login",
"username": "XXXX",
"password": "YYYY"}
```

Response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 04 Dec 2020 07:00:49 GMT
Server: Informatica
```

Nothing else. Are we missing anythig?

Comment: Hi - can you access the URL directly in a browser i.e. paste http://<SERVER>:<PORT>/ma/api/v2/user/login into Chrome?

Comment: @NickW Thanks for the comment. Actually I can access website url that is http://xxxxxxxxxxxx:6605/tdm. But http://xxxxxxxx:6605/ma/api/v2/user/login remains inaccessible (404). Actually I heard REST is supported only in Informatica Cloud and I need to use SOAP

Comment: you can use http transformation too in infa on prem version. you can post your qn and i can answer.

Comment: @KoushikRoy Thanks, I have the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65233111/run-on-prem-informatica-jobs-remotely-from-another-web-app . Can you please answer

Comment: i guess you can use `pmcmd` to kick off workflow from remote. You may need connectivity between the on-prem and cloud.

Comment: Hi Kaushik. We don’t have cloud at all. Just an on Prem instance