# Run On Prem Informatica Jobs remotely from another web app

Tags: java, informatica

We are trying to run an On-Prem Informatica Jobs remotely from another web app (written in Java),
Since this is not cloud, I am not able to use IICS REST API or RunAJobUtil.

Is there an alternate way of triggering a job on an On-Prem Informatica Job? Will HTTP Transformation be any help

Comment: Are you trying to run informatica task? You can use PMCMD to run any workflow remotely. have you tried using it?

Comment: @Koushik Roy thanks. Will try out. Can I run pmcmd without installing anything on the client machine ?

Comment: yes you can, you just have to copy few binaries ( client\bin folder may be). But you can copy into remote.

Comment: Thanks Koushik. Let me try

Comment: @KoushikRoy Hi Koushik, I read that we need to give the server UNC path and directly invoke the pmcmd, Is that the only way?

Comment: You can try copying  few binaries from bin folder ( client\bin folder may be) and store in local in lets say ~/Infa/bin. Then call pmcmd like this `~/Infa/bin/pmcmd xxxx`